# html5 multiply effect with changing background

Tags: jquery, html, background

I want to create the photoshop multiply effect on my images. That's not that difficult, i found out how that works. (see: http://albertogasparin.it/articles/2011/05/html5-multiply-filter-canvas/)

The problem is, I want to combine it with a changing background. I want a coloured background, that fades slowly from one colour to another. The Multiply effet should change in the same way as the background does.

I thought it would be possible to create a variable for the colours, and then place that colour on two objects. It doesn't work. If I do that, I break the syntax, or the image get's black. The latest working version can be found here: http://www.sythe.nl/baum/  (The green canvas has the multiply effect on it)

I converted the background colors to RGB:

```
 var cols = ["rgb(254,240,221)","rgb(248,226,232)"]
```

But now it should also be placed in here:

```
multiplyFilter.init('base', [66, 176, 153]);
```

Can anyone tell me how I should fix this thing. Is it even possible to do? I want the green canvas to change in the same way as the background does.